# How do I merge accounts in Trello?

Tags: trello

I have two accounts in Trello and I'd like to merge them. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9):

It's generally not necessary to merge accounts in Trello. In these situations, there's almost always a more-used and less-used account. The real difficulty usually happens when people invite your less-used account to their board. So you just really want to get rid of that account. Here's how to do it.

1. Log into your less-used account.
2. Invite your more-used account to each board owned by the less-used account.
3. Make your more-used account an **admin** over each board.
4. Leave each of your boards. (You may have to make yourself a non-admin.)
5. Delete your account by going to https://trello.com/my/account and going to the bottom of the page and clicking the **Delete** link.

That's it!

Comment: It's worth noting that once the account is deleted, it is possible to link its google account to the merged account.

Comment: Since this is the [official solution from Trello](http://help.trello.com/article/739-merging-multiple-trello-accounts), this should be marked as the solution for this question until [Trello](https://trello.com/) adds this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear way for that moment, but if trello has [Merging and splitting multiple Trello accounts](http://help.trello.com/article/739-merging-multiple-trello-accounts) post, that says almost the same as [@RichArmstrong](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/30708/126294).